# Pusher ShoutBox

Tags: php, jquery, pusher

I want to built a shoutbox where only group members can talk.
For example I've 5 groups each with 60 members, I have done a similar shoutbox with PHP/MySQL/jQuery but with the increase of members the activity was slow. I came across Pusher (http://www.pusher.com).

All I want to know is what should be my method of approach where I can segregate the members according to their groups and can use the shoutbox.

I'm confused with the event trigger of Pusher. Can anyone please explain me how should I do the approach, also that I need to save the shoutbox message in a mysql database for history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that you would want to use a [channel](http://pusher.com/docs/channels) for each group - use channels to route and filter data.

You would use events if there are different types of group events e.g. `new_shout`, `shout_updated`, `shout_deleted`.

Pusher doesn't presently offer a message history so you would need to store this yourself.